# Any Twitter clients for iPhone with larger font size?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, font, twitter

Are there any Twitter clients for iPhone that have larger font size than the one used in the official Twitter for iPhone app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TweetBot](http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/) allows you to choose a font size, and is generally considered a top drawer twitter client.

[image: Font Options]

[image: Example at Huge]

Comment: you must have missed the first answer

Comment: Nope, just a case of great minds thinking alike, and my 2nd photo adding a few extra steps that meant he beat me to it by a minute :)  We were both writing this at the same time, as evidenced by the time on the screenshots...  Not the first time that's happened!

Comment: ha, thats what i meant, you missed being the first had the same happen a few times to me.

Comment: Yeah, well, I have WAAAY more battery life left than you, so... I win ;)

Comment: I would have won, only I had to redownload it as the website didn't have a suitable screenshot to steal!  I don't actually like it much myself...

Answer (score 3):

Here's [**Tweetbot**](http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/) *Huge* font size.

[image: tweetbot]

Answer (score 2):

Here's [Twitteriffic](http://twitterrific.com/) large size:

[image]